# How to filter a particular class when i have a inheritance?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

I have this code :

```
class A {
  String name
}
class B extends A{

} 
class C extends A{

}
class D{
  A a
}
D d = new D(); d.a = new B()
D d2 = new D(); d.a = new C()
```

My query :

```
D.createCriteria().list(...){
  A{
    eq "a","test" 
  }
}
```

But in my result I would have only the element matching with B class not C class.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I find this  :

```
A{
  eq "class", B.name
}
```

Thank you